# python / django's module / class theory: Template object under django.template.base.Template

Tags: python, django, module

I'm using Django 1.6.5, under the `python manage.py shell`, i create a Template object by:

```
from django.template import Template
t = Template('This is template {{ num }}.')
```

then i `print t`

the result is **NOT** `<django.template.Template object at 0xb7d5f24c>`, but

```
<django.template.base.Template object at 0xb7d5f24c>
```

Can someone explain why `Template` is just under `django.template`, but the created object is under `django.template.base`, and the module theory behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this simply from [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/template): the actual class is in `django.template.base`, but the `__init__.py` file in `django.template` imports the class so as to make it available via a more convenient name.